# Jupyter notebook not trusted

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am using Anaconda to work on a Jupyter notebook which displays "Not Trusted" (see on screenshot below).

[image]

What does it mean? Is it a problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It is a security feature to disable the execution of arbitrary code from untrusted notebooks, without the user's consent. There is a doc page about it: https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operators/security.html#security-in-notebook-documents

It won't prevent you from manually running the code, that's actually one way of "trusting" the outputs.

Answer (score 157):

You can try doing

```
jupyter trust notebook-name.ipynb
```

as is stated in the [docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebook.html?highlight=trust#signing-notebooks).

After that, open the notebook as usual with

```
jupyter notebook notebook-name.ipynb
```

Comment: This is also available in the jupyter GUI, near the bottom of the 'File' menu

Comment: What is the problem if the notebook is not trusted?

Answer (score 26):

Apart from them,
You can click on "Not Trusted"
and click on "Trust" when confirmation window pops up.

Comment: I think jupyter lab latest release 1) this popup never comes up and 2) you cannot chose Trust under the file menu. The only way I see to do it is what @VincentPakson stated.

Comment: Have posted that assuming usage of Jupyter notebook instead of jupyterlab.

Comment: I do not have an updated version of Jupyter notebook. It would be great if someone could confirm if it works there or not.

Answer (score 13):

Open Notebook in Jupyter -> Click File -> Trust Notebook

[image: Pic]

Comment: just upvote because of simplicity but it doesn't work for JupyterLab

Answer (score 9):

For Jupyter lab you can use the command `Trust Notebook`.

The command line can be accessed via `View > Activate Command Palette` or with `Ctrl+Shift+C`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen when you create a notebook in a docker container with mounted volume (the file is owned by the root user) and then open in in jupyter running on the host machine. Changing file owner to the host user helps.

Comment: I'm running my notebook on a docker and the entry-point file runs a script that runs `jupyter trust my_notebook.ipynb` and `jupyter-notebook --no-browser --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --NotebookApp.allow_origin='*' --NotebookApp.allow_remote_access=True --NotebookApp.quit_button=True --NotebookApp.trust_xheaders=True --NotebookApp.open_browser=False --NotebookApp.notebook_dir=/some/path`. The owner of all files in the docker is the same and **not** root. 
When I open the notebook it is still not trusted. 
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the Jupyter lab using the generated link with token from the Command Prompt helped, this link is something like this http://localhost:8888/lab?token=0479d86d921f46a967e3cbb3237e2c9d3210d342ef0c4ebe, copy and paste it into the address bar of your browser and enter.