# Trusting a Jupyter untrusted notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working in an untrusted notebook.  How do I change the notebook's status from "untrusted" to "trusted"? I do not see a "File / Trust" as per the documentation.  Instead, I see a "File / Trusted Notebook" which is not selectable.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter notebook not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943646/jupyter-notebook-not-trusted)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hey Jon, can you point me to an answer I can use in the question you're referencing?  I don't think it's actually a dupe.

Comment: The screenshot you've posted suggests that that's *not* an untrusted notebook, hence the menu option is not shown. And please stop putting tags back in titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After loading the untrusted notebook, with File / Trust Notebook.  It's not explictly spelled out in the documentation, but if you see an unselectable menu item "Trusted Notebook" it means the current notebook is trusted and no further operations are necessary.

from the [Jupyter security docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html)

Comment: Tried that, clarified the question to show that it's not a valid option on my notebook.

Answer (score 0):

At the command line, run:

```
jupyter trust notebook-name.ipynb
```