# jupyter: how to trust to show output

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have got a notebook, but the images are not shown in jupyter-lab.

I was told the output becomes visible, when trusting a notebook.
Indeed, works in Jupyter as explained in [Jupyter notebook not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943646/jupyter-notebook-not-trusted).

However, in my jupyter-lab there is not such a trust button.

[image]

I found this explanation: https://www.legendu.net/en/blog/trust-a-jupyterlab-notebook. But I don't have the palette icon.

So how can I trust the notebook?

Comment: Command palette is now "modal" by default meaning that it shows up as an overlay. To open it use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on Mac) as described in documentation https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/commands.html

Comment: @krassowski Thx! Your comment is worth to be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command palette is now "modal" by default meaning that it shows up as an overlay.

To open it use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on Mac) as described in documentation [JupyterLab Commands](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/commands.html) documentation, and then proceed typing "trust" to find and select the "Trust Notebook" option:

[image]

You should see the indicator in the statusbar turn to a shield with a checkmark indicating trust status ([image]). You can hover over the shield for extra information. There is some additional documentation about the trust mechanism in the JupyterLab [Notebooks](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/notebook.html#trust) documentation (at the very end of the page as of writing).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, continuing with https://www.legendu.net/en/blog/trust-a-jupyterlab-notebook one can also get a "command line" by opening a terminal, and go to the corresponding directory (`ls`, `cd`) and then execute

```
jupyter trust *.ipynb
```

Finally, reopen the notebook.